# Multiple function calling not working

Tags: php, class

I'm getting this issue when i run this script:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setAge() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/index.php on line 16

```
<?php

class Student {

   public function setName($name,$value){
       $this->$name=$value;
   }
   public function setAge($name,$value){
       $this->$name=$value;
   }

}

$Student1=new Student;
$Student1->setName('name', 'sanjeewani')
         ->setAge('age', '26');

var_dump($Student1);
?>
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: do not down vote and leave,say what's wrong with it.Unless he/she never get correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot chain methods like this, you need them to return the object in order to do that. Otherwise you have to call each method separately.

```
   public function setName($name,$value){
       $this->$name=$value;
       return $this;
   }
   public function setAge($name,$value){
       $this->$name=$value;
       return $this;
   }
```

Comment: Note: you should *really* just call them separately otherwise debugging will become a pain.

Answer (score 0):

For a "fluent interface" (calling several methods in a row as you are doing), your methods need to `return $this`. Because you're calling the next method on the return value of the former.

If you're not doing this, you cannot use the fluent interface style. Just do regular method calls:

```
$Student1->setName('name', 'sanjeewani')
$Student1->setAge('age', '26');
```

Also note that your methods are pretty pointless. It should be `setAge(26)`, not `setAge('age', 26)`. Get rid of the redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

i did that for setting object attributes dynamically.if any student have some different feature. then i can setting this. when i print student object for any student i want to see different feature for different student. that the reason i used this.(just ignore the function name)

```
$Student1->setName('name', 'sanjeewani')
$Student1->setAge('age', '26');
```